# Convert nested for loop logic to for each and java stream

Tags: java, for-loop, java-stream

The code below will skip the string at index i=0,j=0 and if it occurs again anywhere. Also it will add an additional header if finaldata list is empty or whenever the finaldata string becomes of size 1000. I wish to write the same code using for each loop and java stream syntax. Can somebody help me out?

```
List<List<String>> completedata=new ArrayList<>(); // Suppose it contains many lists which have around 5000 strings in total
List<String> finaldata=new ArrayList<>();
String header="Heading";
String temp=null;
for(int i=0;i<completedata.size();i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < completedata.get(i).size(); j++) {
                if ((i == 0 || j == 0) || completedata.get(i).get(j).equals(temp)) {
                    temp = completedata.get(i).get(j);
                    continue;
                }
                if (finaldata.size() == 0 || (finaldata.size() % 1000 == 0)) {
                    finaldata.add(header);
                }
                finaldata.add(completedata.get(i).get(j));
        }
}
```

Comment: if this is for homework (which it looks highly likely to me), please consult with this FAQ https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: especially this one is relevant: 

Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first. Users here respond negatively if your question gives them the impression that you're asking them to do your work for you. On the other hand, questions which ask about a specific issue which you're having a problem with usually receive a much better response.

Comment: Well I wasn't able to proceed with it and that's why I asked for help here

Comment: what exactly is not working for you?

Comment: don't know much about java stream syntax

Comment: I think your code is not working correct. With "i==0" in the first if-statement all entries with i=0 are ignored. And if you don't want dupplicated strings in the result this construction with temp will not work.

Comment: @ChristianAlderson if you read this, will it help ? https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-streams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this task comes from the definition.

- If list of lists should be converted to plain `List`, `Stream::flatMap` is used
- If it is needed to skip list elements at indexes 0, then `Stream::skip(1)` should be used.
- If no duplicate elements are needed, then `Stream::distinct` should be applied.
- If some values need to be added to the resulting list, `Collectors.collectingAndThen` may be used along with the `IntStream.range` to calculate the indexes where `"Heading"` needs to be inserted.

To sum it up, an example implementation can look like:

```java
public static final List<String> formatData(List<List<String>> data, String header, int afterN) {
    return data.stream().skip(1) // skip i == 0
               .flatMap(lst -> lst.stream().skip(1)) // skip j == 0, make flat list
               .distinct() // remove duplicates
               .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                       Collectors.toList(),
                       lst -> IntStream.range(0, lst.size()).boxed()
                               .flatMap(i -> i % afterN == 0
                                       ? Stream.of(header, lst.get(i))
                                       : Stream.of(lst.get(i))
                               )
                               .collect(Collectors.toList())
               ));
}
```

Test

```java
List<List<String>> data = Arrays.asList(
        Arrays.asList("Skipped line"),
        Arrays.asList("Skipped column 1", "column1", "column2", "column3"),
        Arrays.asList("Skipped column 2", "value 2.1", "value 2.2", "value 2.3"),
        Arrays.asList("Skipped column 3", "value 3.1", "value 3.2", "value 3.3"),
        Arrays.asList("Skipped column 4", "value 4.1", "value 4.2", "value 4.3"),
        Arrays.asList("Skipped column 5", "value 5.1", "value 5.2", "value 5.3", "value 5.3"),
        Arrays.asList("Skipped column 6", "6.1", "6.2", "6.3", "value 5.1", "value 4.2"),
        Arrays.asList("Skipped column 7", "7.1", "7.2", "7.3", "7.1", "7.3"),
        Arrays.asList("Skipped column 8", "8.1", "8.2", "8.3", "8.4", "8.4", "8.5")
);

// use \n to improve output, insert header after each 3 elements
List<String> finalData = formatData(data, "\nHeader", 3); 

System.out.println(finalData);
```

Output (without duplicate elements)

```
[
Header, column1, column2, column3, 
Header, value 2.1, value 2.2, value 2.3, 
Header, value 3.1, value 3.2, value 3.3, 
Header, value 4.1, value 4.2, value 4.3, 
Header, value 5.1, value 5.2, value 5.3, 
Header, 6.1, 6.2, 6.3, 
Header, 7.1, 7.2, 7.3, 
Header, 8.1, 8.2, 8.3, 
Header, 8.4, 8.5]
```